# How is possible indexpath.row = -1 in editActionsForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am using `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` in my app for delete & edit button but if I again & again more time swipe so at a time I'm getting `indexpath.row = -1` I am shocked for that how is possible but I have check & visit more demo project everywhere I am getting same `indexpath.row = -1`.
So how can I handle that, like I want swipe is not working in this condition.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    print(indexPath.row)
    //Edit
    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Edit", handler: {
        action in
    })
    editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 212.0/255, green: 37.0/255, blue: 37.0/255, alpha: 1)

    //Delete
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete", handler: {
        action in
    })
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 183.0/255, green: 27.0/255, blue: 27.0/255, alpha: 1)
    return [deleteAction,editAction]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what causes this, probably an issue with the method trying to access a cell that no longer exists, but a quick, dirty fix is to just check if the indexPath has a -1 and if it does returning nil.

```
if(indexPath.section != -1 && indexPath.row != -1) {
    //Code for creating actions
}
return nil
```

This should at least stop it crashing when this indexPath appears.

Comment: And then one will have the crash with `-2`? Better check what is calling this function with a negative value and avoid the call entirely. In the case where it would be a system issue, then it would be important to make a sample project and report it to https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/welcome